# ARKit Reference image - The histogram of the image is narrow - programming

Tags: swift, histogram, arkit

Is it possible to calculate programmatically (not by looking at the histogram) if there is skew / narrow histogram? and how "bad" it is in percentage?

I wish to simulate programmatically the same warning I get from XCODE when adding a problematic image.

I can easily create a histogram but I'm lacking the exact math that comes after it.